# PHP - Form mail inserting ! and line break into long strings

Tags: php, email, mail-form

I have a form on my company's site which takes a name, telephone number, and comments (and a couple other things). The comments box lets you type up to 5000 characters - a large limit to allow for very verbose customers. A valid form has its contents sent using php form mail as a plain-text e-mail to our sales dept.

For some reason, if the Comments are longer than about 1000 characters, they will have and exclamation point, a line break, and sometimes an indent inserted in. Note this applies to the e-mail only; if the form has an error in it, the data gets inserted into the form and errors are marked, and the comments do not have the exclamation marks + line breaks yet.

I found one forum post about it suggesting that there is a character limit of about 990 characters that leads to this problem.

Does anyone know the cause? Does anyone know a fairly easy fix for this?

Relevant PHP code:

```
$to = $email;

$subject = "Website Order Received: $offer";

$contents = "
Order Form Received -\n
Name: $name\n
Company: $company\n
Email: $email\n
Phone: $phone $phoneExt\n
Order Contents:\n" .
($offer == 'web-demo' ? "- I want a live software demonstration.\n" : "") .
($offer == 'pricing' ? "- I'd like pricing information.\n" : "") .
($offer == 'holiday-pricing' ? "- I'd like to sign up before December 31st for the special holiday offer!\n" : "") .
($offer == 'bid-help' ? "- Please give me marketing materials and other assistance for winning bids.\n" : "") .
($offer == 'demo-cd' ? "- Send me the full-version demonstration CD.\n" : "");
if (!empty ($comments)) {
    $comments = str_replace("
", "\n", $comments); // Preserves line breaks in the comments.
    $contents = $contents."\nComments: $comments\n\n";
}
$contents = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $contents);

mail($to, $subject, $contents);
```

Comment: Do you have the PHP script that sends the mail for us to inspect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a limit to the number of characters in a line of an email:

> There are two limits that this standard places on the number of characters in a line. Each line of characters MUST be no more than 998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding the CRLF. [(RFC 2882)](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)

You can use the PHP function [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) to achieve this:

```
$contents = wordwrap($contents);
```

In any case, this will improve the readability of the emails sent with your script, as well as making them standards-compliant.

Comment: Why does the answer give more than just the line "$contents = wordwrap ..." ?
Why does the code then have two occurrences of "str_replace" after that?

Comment: @MarkGoldfain That's a very good question, to which I don't know the answer these six years later. Edited.